# Inequality of sizes of finite sets

Tags: inequality, integers, additive-combinatorics

For a set $A\subset \mathbb N$, define
$$A+c\cdot A=\{a+c\cdot a'|a,a'\in A\}$$

Is it true that for every such finite set $A$ $$\frac{|A+2A|}{|A|}\leq\left(\frac{|A+A|}{|A|}\right)^3$$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed true: we have $2A \subset A+A$, hence
$$ 
|A+2A| \leq |A+A+A| \leq \sigma(A)^3 |A|,
$$
where $\sigma(A)=\frac{|A+A|}{|A|}$. The last inequality follows from the famous Plünnecke inequality (for instance, see [here](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-new-way-of-proving-sumset-estimates/)). The result holds for any finite subset $A$ of any additive group.

Comment: That was fast :). Is it known if the inequality is tight (is there a set for which this is equal)?

Comment: Plünnecke's inequality is strict when $\sigma(A) > 1$, which in your context of the positive integers means that it only gives an equality for one-element sets $A$. See here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.7536v2.pdf.